# OSX Quicklook debugging

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight, quicklook

I am writing a quicklook plugin for an MPO file.

The plugin isn't that much of a problem, but the problem is trying to debug it. Apples documentation says that to debug you use

```
qlmanage -r <filename>
```

And I have. However, none of my breakpoints are matched. I assume this is as it hasn't matched my quicklook plugin with the type. Using mdl (or mdimport) i get a filetype of dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8046dt. Using that I get nothing. I have played around with the info.plist, as I assume that is the problem, and I have looked at other plugins to fix that, but still no breakpoints hit and it is not using my code.

My (important parts of) info.plist currently looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>QLGenerator</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8046dt</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>QLGenerator</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.image.mpo</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
...

    <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.image</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>MPO Image file</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>MPO</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>public.image.mpo</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>mpo</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Is there anything obviously that I am missing here, or any other reason that it is not executing my plugin?

Comment: google "quicklook generator debugging", click on first apple link.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I followed the apple page on debugging quicklook generators which says about using the qlmanage -r, and that isn't working which is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, it will only debug something that is already in the /Library/QuickLook folder.

So now produced and available [from here](http://alienrat.net/software/stereoscopy.html)